# UITableView IN ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, scrollview

Well I have a view of this type of hierarchy

```
                        Main View (having some Functions as well)

                            |
                        ScrollView (added now)
                            |
                         UIView (having other features)
                            |
                        UITableView (loading from xmls)
```

i know that this type of view hierarchy is not recommended by apple, but at last moment my client need the whole view in scrollview, as my base was only a view (having some other features) an i added a table view there( which is loading through xmls,so cant change or edit tableview), now after adding a scroll view in my main view , my last cell (custom cell) of tableView is not responding on click (in Some Area).

I cant add header or footer in my table for solving my prob !!!

I am totally confused now wat can i do ????

pls suggest me anything so that my TableView can respond Properly....

TIA !!!

Comment: check your tableview's last cell or your view's bottom cell not responding

Comment: I am using custom cell and there display is all correct in Scroll view evev scrolling is also fine, only it does not respond on clicking it means didSelectAtRowIndexPath is not responding for last Custom Cell (I think)...

Comment: do one thing change the background color of every view and check if any of view is over the table or not. many times this approach help me

Comment: @ Hiren443 - Thanks Actually UIView' height in which TableView was attached, was less then tableView Height thats why its not responding, can detect only after applying BG color. :)

Comment: good if you really use my tips then up the arrow comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide more information - how are these hierarchies being built? where and what are the relations between them? I suspect it is a problem with a view blocking your touch events, but we can't know for sure unless you provide information. As a start, I would try and give each view in the hierarchy a tag, and add a category for UIView that contains the following:

UIView+Debug.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface UIView (Debug) 

@end
```

UIView+Debug.m:

```
#import "UIView+Debug.h"

@implementation UIView (Debug)


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch caught on %@\n",NSStringFromClass([self class]));
    NSLog(@"Tag: %d",[self tag]);
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


@end
```

This way, you'll know which of the views is "stealing" your touch events in each area. Good luck!

Comment: I dont think so because while scrolling all the rows are working fine except last one.